# modelsearch not working in yii2

Tags: php, web, phpmyadmin, yii2

I have some problems in making modelsearch in yii2.

Here's is my table's relation
[image]

I want to display **Jurusan** from table **aitambah** to **ais3** and I want to display **NamaMahasiswa** from table **ai** to **ais3**. I made table **s3penghubung** so that table **aitambah** can be related to **ais3**. I was able to display them. But, when I try to type "71501" in "NRP" field, the searching not working properly.  it is refreshing the page. there is no any change to the rows displayed. so, what should I do to fix that? 
[image]

here is my modelsearch codes:

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;
use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;
use app\models\Ais3;

/**
 * Ais3Search represents the model behind the search form about `app\models\Ais3`.
 */
class Ais3Search extends Ais3
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['id', 'kode'], 'integer'],
            [['NRP', 'namaMahasiswaText', 'ProgramStudi', 'TanggalMasuk', 'TanggalKeluar'], 'safe'],
        ];
    }

    public $NamaMahasiswa;
    public $namaMahasiswaText;


    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function scenarios()
    {
        // bypass scenarios() implementation in the parent class
        return Model::scenarios();
    }

    /**
     * Creates data provider instance with search query applied
     *
     * @param array $params
     *
     * @return ActiveDataProvider
     */
    public function search($params)
    {
        $query = Ais3::find();
        $query->joinWith('ai');

        // add conditions that should always apply here

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
        ]);

        $this->load($params);

        if (!$this->validate()) {
            // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
            // $query->where('0=1');
            return $dataProvider;
        }

        // grid filtering conditions
        $query->andFilterWhere([
            'id' => $this->id,
            'kode' => $this->kode,
        ]);

        $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'ais3.NRP', $this->NRP])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'ai.NamaMahasiswa', $this->namaMahasiswaText])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'ais3.ProgramStudi', $this->ProgramStudi])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'ai.TanggalMasuk', $this->TanggalMasuk])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'ais3.TanggalKeluar', $this->TanggalKeluar]);

        return $dataProvider;
    }
}
```

**here is mygridview codes**

```
<?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

            //'id',
            'NRP',
            'namaMahasiswaText',
            'ProgramStudi',
            //'TanggalMasuk',
            [
            'attribute' => 'TanggalMasuk',
            'value' => function($data) {
                return $data->ai->TanggalMasuk;
            },],
            'TanggalKeluar',

            //YANG DITAMBAH
            [
                'attribute'=>'NRP',
                'value'=>'s3penghubung.aitambah.JURUSAN',
                'label' => 'Jurusan',
            ],

            [
                'attribute'=>'NRP',
                'value'=>'s3penghubung.aitambah.NAMKANTOR',
                'label' => 'Nama Kantor',
            ],
            [
                'attribute'=>'NRP',
                'value'=>'s3penghubung.aitambah.ANGKATAN',
                'label' => 'Angkatan',
            ],
            [
                'attribute'=>'NRP',
                'value'=>'s3penghubung.aitambah.TELP',
                'label' => 'Nomor HP/Telp',
            ],
            [
                'attribute'=>'NRP',
                'value'=>'s3penghubung.aitambah.PEKERJAAN',
                'label' => 'Pekejaan',
            ],
            [
                'attribute'=>'NRP',
                'value'=>'s3penghubung.aitambah.EMAIL',
                'label' => 'Email',
            ],
            [
                'attribute'=>'NRP',
                'value'=>'s3penghubung.aitambah.KODEPROP',
                'label' => 'KodeProp',
            ],


            // 'kode',

            ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ],
    ]); ?>
```

I thought there must be something wrong in my query filter

```
$query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'ais3.NRP', $this->NRP])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'ai.NamaMahasiswa', $this->namaMahasiswaText])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'ais3.ProgramStudi', $this->ProgramStudi])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'ai.TanggalMasuk', $this->TanggalMasuk])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'ais3.TanggalKeluar', $this->TanggalKeluar]);
```

but I dont know how to fix those codes. Could you please help me to solve this? Thankyou

**The right answer is here:** 
here's gridview in index
[image]

and here's in modelsearch
[image]

thankyou **ck_anjuk** for solving my problem.

Comment: How is the filter responding ? Is it refreshing the page ? Is there any change to the rows displayed ?

Comment: yes, it is refreshing the page. there is no any change to the rows displayed. so, what should I do to fix that?

Comment: Please show your gridview code . Search function looks ok

Comment: I have edited my question and put gridview code. you could see that code in the question above

Comment: please help me to solve this code. thankyou

Comment: Well you have named most of your attribute as `NRP` !! You should give different value for attribute for each column in grid view

Comment: `[
                'attribute'=>'NRP',
                'value'=>'s3penghubung.aitambah.KODEPROP',
                'label' => 'KodeProp',
            ],`   and simply putting 'NRP' is kind of same. You are just displaying same attribute multiple times with different values.

Comment: You should also make sure that the attribute name(for related fields) you give in gridview should be declared as public property in `Ais3Search` class. Also give the same in rules array under safe.

Comment: hello ck_arjun. I've made the code like you said. and I've edited my question above. could you please see whether there are something wrong on my code? because when I try to run it, the search field in NRP is dissapear

Comment: Search filed for the column `NRP` is missing because you removed `NRP` from rules. Only the attributes given in rules will have search field.

Comment: Have a look at these also: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/653/displaying-sorting-and-filtering-model-relations-on-a-gridview/ and http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/621/filter-sort-by-calculated-related-fields-in-gridview-yii-2-0/

Comment: wow, finally it works. I have added "NRP" in attribute. thankyou so much ck_arjun. God bless you O:)

Comment: hello ck_arjun. searching in colomn NRP is working. but searching in colomn Jurusan is not working. What should I do to fix that? Thankyou xx